# Interactive Data Visualisations

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2, powerbi

So I have finally gotten a hold of ggplot2 and ggvis packages and tried out shiny too to have interactive graphics and visualizations. but i have been using Power BI before and came to R as a an good alternative for creating effective visualizations. But there is one thing that has been missing in R which is to be able to filter out all visualizations on a page on the basis of a mouse click in one of the visualizations on the page. I understand how we can create slicers and other ways to filter graphics using shiny or better with ggvis.

So can anyone suggest a package or something i have missed in the above packages to help me achieve this.

Comment: I don't know if I got it, but do you want something to select a filter that impact on all of your graphics?

Comment: @thebiro yes exactly. but that select will be on the basis of the click on one of the graphics.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the `plotly`package a try. You basically code up the plot you want first with `ggplot2` and then call `ggplotly()` at the end, which will render an interactive version of it. You get zooming in on mouse selection for example and labels of points on hover. It has a pretty extensive documentation too. I can try and help you out with a specific example if you post some code. Another cool package you can check out is `trelliscopejs`. hth